# R: Reading and writing multiple csv files into a loop then using original names for output

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, export

Apologies if this may seem simple, but I can't find a workable answer anywhere on the site.
My data is in the form of a csv with the filename being a name and number. Not quite as simple as having file with a generic word and increasing number...
I've achieved exactly what i want to do with just one file, but the issue is there are a couple of hundred to do, so changing the name each time is quite tedious.

Posting my original single-batch code here in the hopes someone may be able to ease the growing tension of failed searches.

```
# set workspace
getwd()
setwd(".../Desktop/R Workspace")


# bring in original file, skipping first four rows
Person_7<- read.csv("PersonRound7.csv", header=TRUE, skip=4)

# cut matrix down to 4 columns
Person7<- Person_7[,c(1,2,9,17)]

# give columns names
colnames(Person7) <- c("Time","Spare", "Distance","InPeriod")

# find the empty rows, create new subset. Take 3 rows away for empty lines.
nullrow <- (which(Person7$Spare == "Velocity"))-3
Person7 <- Person7[(1:nullrow), ]

#keep 3 needed columns from matrix
Person7<- Person7[,c(1,3,4)]
colnames(Person7) <- c("Time","Distance","InPeriod")

#convert distance and time columns to factors
options(digits=9)
Person7$Distance <- as.numeric(as.character(Person7$Distance))
Person7$Time <- as.numeric(as.character(Person7$Time))

#Create the differences column for distance
Person7$Diff <- c(0, diff(Person7$Distance))

...whole heap of other stuff...

#export Minutes to an external file
write.csv(Person7_maxs, ".../Desktop/GPS Minutes/Person7.csv")
```

So the three part issue is as follows:

1. I can create a list or vector to read through the file names, but not a dataframe for each, each time (if that's even a good way to do it).
2. The variable names throughout the code will need to change instead of just being "Person1" "Person2", they'll be more like "Johnny1" "Lou23".
3. Need to export each resulting dataframe to it's own csv file with the original name.

Taking any and all suggestions on board - s.t.ruggling with this one.
Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using one list of the ~200 dataframes. No need for separate named objects flooding global environment (though `list2env` still shown below). Hence, use `lapply()` to iterate through all csv files of working directory, then simply name each element of list to basename of file:

```
setwd(".../Desktop/R Workspace")

files <- list.files(path=getwd(), pattern=".csv")

# CREATE DATA FRAME LIST
dfList <- lapply(files, function(f) {
      df <- read.csv(f, header=TRUE, skip=4)
      df <- setNames(df[c(1,2,9,17)], c("Time","Spare","Distance","InPeriod"))

      # ...same code referencing temp variable, df

      write.csv(df_max, paste0(".../Desktop/GPS Minutes/", f))
      return(df)
})

# NAME EACH ELEMENT TO CORRESPONDING FILE'S BASENAME 
dfList <- setNames(dfList, gsub(".csv", "", files))

# REFERENCE A DATAFRAME WITH LIST INDEXING
str(dfList$PersonRound7)    # PRINT STRUCTURE
View(dfList$PersonRound7)   # VIEW DATA FRAME
dfList$PersonRound7$Time    # OUTPUT ONE COLUMN

# OUTPUT ALL DFS TO SEPARATE OBJECTS (THOUGH NOT NEEDED)
list2env(dfList, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Since you are not using `f` anywhere, you can set `list.files(pattern = ".csv", full.names = TRUE)` and you won't have to construct a file name when writing a csv.

Comment: Thanks, I had the previous `i` variable used. But `f` is now used in `read.csv` and `write.csv` lines. And `full.names` arg is not needed as OP sets a defined working directory. Not quite sure what you mean on last point as the output csv is being saved to a different directory than input.

Comment: Guys, this is incredible. Thank you so much.